# How to make half of the ImageView on top of custom navigationbar in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uinavigationbar

I am using custom navigation bar for all viewcontrollers.. but in one of my viewcontroller i need half of the image on top of navigationbar, how to do that? please do help

**like this i need**

[image]

for design i am using storyboard,
for that i have taken one imageview inside uiview

uiview constraints

```
 top = 0, leading = 0, trailing = 0, height = 100
```

imageview constraints

```
 top = -40, horizontal center, height, width = 80
```

now i am getting like this

[image]

my code for custom navigation bar: **please help me to make imageview on top of navigationbar in one viewcontroller**

```
 func updateNavigationBar(with title : String, isTransparent : Bool = false, isBackNeed : Bool = true, isNotificationNeed : Bool = true, isMenuNeed : Bool = true){
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
    if isTransparent{
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 0
    }else{
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = CommonColor.navigationColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = CommonColor.navigationColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    }
    let btnTitle = UIBarButtonItem(title: title, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backClick))
    btnTitle.tintColor = .white
    
    let backImageView = UIImageView.init(image: CommonImage.back?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))
    backImageView.tintColor = .white
    backImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    backImageView.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,y:0.0, width:20,height:25.0)
    backImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    backImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    backImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    backImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(backClick)))
    let btnBack = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backImageView)
    
    let menuImageView = UIImageView.init(image: CommonImage.menu?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))
    menuImageView.tintColor = .white
    menuImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    menuImageView.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,y:0.0, width:25,height:25.0)
    menuImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    menuImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    menuImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    menuImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(menuClick)))
    let btnMenu = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuImageView)
    
    let notificatonView = UIView()
    notificatonView.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,y:0.0, width:32,height:32.0)
    notificatonView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    notificatonView.alpha = 0.5
    notificatonView.backgroundColor = .white
    notificatonView.clipsToBounds = true
    notificatonView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
    notificatonView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
    notificatonView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(notificationClick)))
    
    let notificationBtn: BadgeButton = BadgeButton(type: .custom)
    notificationBtn.setImage(CommonImage.notification, for: .normal)
    notificationBtn.addAction(for: .touchUpInside) {
        
    }
    notificationBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    notificationBtn.badgeBackgroundColor = CommonColor.navigationColor
    notificationBtn.badgeTextColor = .white
    if notificatonView.subviews.filter({$0 is BadgeButton}).count == 0{
        notificatonView.addSubview(notificationBtn)
        notificationBtn.center = notificatonView.center
    }
    let notificationBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: notificatonView)
    if isBackNeed{
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([btnBack,btnTitle], animated: true)
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems( isNotificationNeed ? [notificationBarButton,btnMenu] : [notificationBarButton], animated: true)
    }else{
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems( isMenuNeed ? [btnMenu,btnTitle] : [btnTitle], animated: true)
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems( isNotificationNeed ? [notificationBarButton] : nil, animated: true)
    }
}
```

how to show half of the imageview on top of navigationbar please do help

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your custom navigation controller so we able to achieve this type of design.

Comment: i have already created custom navigationbar, pls take a look on my question, but in this viewcontroller i need image on top of navigationbar, how? how to change my custom navigationbar according to this.. pls do help

Comment: @iosswift you need to make on top our view which is contain image view you facing issue because our view behind navigation

Answer (score 0):

You need using this type of approach[image]

Comment: i am not using custom navigationbar on viewcontroller.. custom navigationbar coming from another swift file.. in question i have added the code for custom navigationbar